# Routes in Rails SAML IdP

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, saml-2.0

I'm trying to get [this gem](https://github.com/sportngin/saml_idp) to work with Rails 4 application that will serve as a SAML identity provider.

The thing that is confusing me is the routes and the template I assume should be rendered. In the gem controller, there is this:

```
def new
  render template: "saml_idp/idp/new"
end
```

My routes are just the basic setup from the example, which I assume should match the action in my custom controller that inherits from the gem controller.

I have this in my controller.

```
class SamlIdpController < SamlIdp::IdpController

  def idp_authenticate(email, password)
    true
  end

  def idp_make_saml_response(user)
    encode_SAMLResponse("you@example.com")
  end
end
```

And my routes.rb file:

```
get '/saml/auth' => 'saml_idp#new'
get '/saml/metadata' => 'saml_idp#show'
```

So, what am I missing here? There should be a view rendered, instead I'm getting No Route Matches errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per Doc, I think you missed including `SamlIdp::IdpController` module

please include `SamlIdp::IdpController` rather than excluding.

Hope, It will work.

Comment: Yep, tried that (as in the Doc) and getting this on the include line: TypeError in SamlIdpController#new
wrong argument type Class (expected Module)

Comment: did you remove extended class?

Comment: Yes. Just like in the doc example.

Comment: and please try with extend controller with ApplicationController

Comment: It's werid. Got it working with the very setup in my original post. Can access the routes now but getting this now on /saml/auth: `Started GET "/saml/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-20 12:55:46 +0200
Processing by SamlIdpController#new as HTML
One and only one of authnrequest and logout request is required. authnrequest: false logout_request: false 
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
Filter chain halted as :validate_saml_request rendered or redirected
Completed 403 Forbidden in 23ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
`

Comment: put this line on controller skip_before_filter :validate_saml_request, only: [:new, :create]

Comment: Yes! It works now! Should it be like this or what? Do I need a working service provider to fix this issue? This is my first contact with SAML ever, and I'm confused how this gem works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The new update for saml_idp gem wants to include `SamlIdp::Controller` as a module. And the controller class can inherit from `ApplicationController`

In your case it will be:

```
class SamlIdpController < ApplicationController
  include SamlIdp::Controller
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The views are no longer included with the gem.

https://github.com/saml-idp/saml_idp/wiki/Rails_Integration#create-your-view-for-get-request-saml-sp-initiated-request